# Can you find out the IP SSH-ing your computer?

Tags: ssh, terminal, ip

If computer A SSHs computer B, can computer B find the IP of computer A? If so, how?

Comment: Handy when using C9.io or other services to get to EC2, and then re-restricting the network traffic rules to that IP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SSH connection info is also stored in the `SSH_CONNECTION` environmental variable.

You should be able to view this by entering `echo $SSH_CONNECTION`.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Just run netstat:

```
netstat --tcp --numeric
```

Look for the IP using the port 22. `--numeric` forces netstat to show IPs and `--tcp` only shows TCP connections

Comment: Oh and how do I do that on a Mac?

Comment: According to the manpage here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/netstat.1.html you should type netstat -n. There is no tcp filtering.

Comment: For convenience `netstat --tcp --numeric | grep :22`   However, it will show all SSH connections to the server, not the one you are in, which I think is implied in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and here is how in Windows:

The `netstat -a` command shows all conections as they happen.

[image]

I am not a Linux guru, but it is very similar, and the actual base command is the same, I believe:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/netstat-command-examples/

Comment: For the record you would be looking for an IP address with :22 at the end.

Answer (score 1):

For SSH on a specific interface, you can also use

```
tcpdump -i interface port 22
```

This will work for linux and mac and if you have a [tcpdump port for windows](http://www.microolap.com/products/network/tcpdump/download/), it will work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you want, in a terminal:

```
lsof -i :ssh
```

it gives you the names (if available of computers sshin into your computer), if you speficically want their IP address, maybe you want to `ping` the name to see the IP or do an `nslookup` or go to http://ip2location.com ....